# How to use AFNetworking in this situation？

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I must get a various servers list from a master server which maintains the running servers info.When some of the running server is down，it will be remove from the running servers list.

The app must request the  master api to get the running servers list when the app starts.When some requests to the running servers failed,it must request to the master to refresh the running server list.

AFNetworking is asynchronous,how to let the master api's request is completed before requests to the running servers? How to design this logic with asynchronous api elegantly:

```
1 failed to request to the running servers.
2 request the master to refresh the servers list.
3 try to request the running servers again.
```

Comment: request the master in the app delegate and sleeps for some seconds.don't know know to refresh when some server is down.

Comment: What language are you using ??? Lemme write up the code for you :| as per your approach is concerned I must say its pretty bad

Comment: i use objective-c,afnetworking.

Comment: I have given you the pseudo code and the logic have a look

Comment: thanks ,i will read your code at first.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear.Just a question a pattern of design.Why too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is to make use of blocks or delegates to inform other classes about the changes rather then putting the thread to sleep. Because am very much comfirtable with blocks lemme use blocks here.

The code provided here is only meant for explaining the concept and copy pasting may never work.

**What to do :**

1. I prefere creating a singleton class for web services though its completely optional and depends on your coding practices.
2. Have an array either in singleton model class that you will create to hold the array of currently running server or have a variable in app delegate so that it can be accessed by all the classes (preferably have a private variable and write setter and getter for it and make them public but then its up to you to declare property in .h as well)
3. Have a method in singleton class or in appdelegate that takes the completionblock as parameter and which will hit the master server get all the currently active servers and populate the array in model class and then invoke the completion block.
4. In ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear of your firstViewController check if array is nil or not if yes make call to the above declared method and pass a completion block to it when done your completion block will be involved and by the time it is invoked you will have the aray of urls as well.
5. Whenever url fails and server seems to be down call the same method again and pass the completion block to it repeat the same method as explained above.

**Code**

Assuming you are using AFNetworking updated version and making use of blocks here is the code. Even if you are using delegate approcah will be same.

Lets assume you have written a method named getActiveServers in appDelegate,

```
-(void)getActiveServers:(void(^)(NSError *)) completionBlock {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:@"http://myURL.com/user" parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         //process the response get the array
        //save it in array variable
        self.activeServerArray = [responseObject valueForKey:@"serverArray"];
        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock(nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(error);
    }];
}
```

In viewDidLoad of yourViewControllers that makes the webservice call or at the beginning of any class that makes the webService class for that matter,

considering the example of ViewController here,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(appDelegate.activeServerArray) {
           //get the url you want and call your method to make webservice call
    }
    else {
         [appdelegate getActiveServers:^(NSError *) {
               if(error) {
                     //show alert fetching active server failed
               }
               else {
                   //call your method to make webservice call
               }
         }];
    }
```

Finally in your method that calls the webservice if it finds out that server is down,

```
-(void)myMethodToMakeWebServiceCall {
     //realised server down
     appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [appdelegate getActiveServers:^(NSError *) {
           if(error) {
                 //show alert fetching active server failed
           }
           else {
                //call the same method to fetch the data now with updated url
                [self myMethodToMakeWebServiceCall];
           }
     }];
}
```

Comment: understood and I know how to design,every http request will call getActiveServers with a block as parameter to assure the server list is prepared.Does what I think is right?

Comment: @user2219372 : YES :) Have a array or better dictionary to cache all the urls. Everytime you have to make webservice call check if url exists if yes use it else make a call and wait for response in completion block :) And if you realise the server down get new set of active servers and repeat the process thats all :)

Comment: Thanks very much,:)  The question perplexed me for some days.It's resoved by your answers.Thanks for your kindfull answer.:)

Comment: @user2219372 : Always welcome buddy :). Though I must say only problemwith this approch would be if multiple webservice fail at the same time and realise all the servers down they all will end up making call to getActiveServers which is little in efficient but considering thats a very rare case its ok I guess and please access the array or dictionary to save urls in thread safe manner or it may crash :) All the best :) This approach is better then notifications and less in code compared to delegate :)